# Multicollinearity (or not) in exploratory factor analysis

Tags: factor-analysis, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor, determinant

I’m performing an exploratory factor analysis with 28 items, n = 300.
I’m confused whether I have a multicollinearity problem or not, and if so whether/how I go about choosing items to remove from the model.

SPSS tells me that the Determinant = 2.395E-10, which is much smaller than 0.00001, suggesting multicollinearity.

However, I’m struggling to determine where the problem(s) lie.

Average VIF is 2.8.  Only one item has a VIF > 4.  None have VIF > 5. All have VIF > 1.5.

Average correlation between items ranges from r = .38 to r = .59. 16 of the items have correlations r > .70, but only with one or two other items, and there are no correlations where r > .79.

Based on my understanding of these statistics, I don’t have a clear sense of which items may be problematic.  I’ve been exploring by removing the most highly correlated or highest VIF items until the determinant is lower than 0.00001, but it does not feel rigorous. Is there even a problem?!

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Can you give your dataset here /link to, for inspection?